# how to concatenate the OutputPathPlaceholder with a string with Kubeflow pipelines?

Tags: kubeflow-pipelines, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am using Kubeflow pipelines (KFP) with GCP Vertex AI pipelines. I am using `kfp==1.8.5` (kfp SDK) and `google-cloud-pipeline-components==0.1.7`. Not sure if I can find which version of Kubeflow is used on GCP.

I am bulding a component (yaml) using python inspired form this [Github issue](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/3748#issuecomment-627698554). I am defining an output like:

```
outputs=[(OutputSpec(name='drt_model', type='Model'))]
```

This will be a base output directory to store few artifacts on Cloud Storage like model checkpoints and model.

I would to keep one base output directory but add sub directories depending of the artifact:

- <output_dir_base>/model
- <output_dir_base>/checkpoints
- <output_dir_base>/tensorboard

but I didn't find how to concatenate the **OutputPathPlaceholder('drt_model')** with a string like **'/model'**.

How can append extra folder structure like /model or /tensorboard to the OutputPathPlaceholder that KFP will set during run time ?

Comment: I'd advice you to have separate outputs. This way you can easily pass the model to "Upload Tensorflow model to Vertex AI" component while passing the Tensorboard output somewhere else. The "Upload Tensorflow model to Vertex AI" won't accept your multi-directory output. It needs a model.

Comment: BTW, is there a reason you're manually creating `ComponentSpec`/`component.yaml` components using Python structures? Usually, people either write `component.yaml` themselves or generate it via `create_component_from_func`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realized in the first place that `ConcatPlaceholder` accept both Artifact and string. This is exactly what I wanted to achieve:

```
ConcatPlaceholder([OutputPathPlaceholder('drt_model'), '/model'])
```